Отображается номер получателя в Kannel как "1234"
У меня есть подключенный модем с сим-картой.
Я предполагаю, что Kannel должен брать информацию о номере данной сим-карты используя команду AT+CNUM. AT+CNUM в minicom возвращает мне установленный номер телефона, но в Kannel в поле "to" GET-запроса на указанный мной url также остается "1234", как будто номер не определился.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? Как вообще Kannel определяет номер телефона?
